# Hide angular material mat-tab using directive

Tags: html, angular, angular-material2

I am using angular material tabs and I want to use a directive to hide a tab element dynamically.

html template

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <!-- how to hide this using a directive? -->
  <mat-tab appHideMe label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <!-- like this -->
  <mat-tab *ngIf="false" label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

<div appHideMe>
  hidden
</div>
<div>
  visible
</div>
```

`HideMe` directive

```ts
    @Directive({
      selector: '[appHideMe]'
    })
    export class HideMeDirective implements AfterViewInit {
      constructor(
        private el: ElementRef
      ) { }
    
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.el.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
```

As during compilation, `mat-tab` is replaced so `display = 'none'` will not work. Is there any way how to hide `mat-tab` like `*ngIf` does (using `HideMeDirective`)?

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqc1co?file=app%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html) is a stackblitz example.

---

I also want `mat-tab` to be toggleable. In [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqc1co-9xw1rb) example I expect `third` to be visible but it is not.

template

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <!-- how to hide this using directive? -->
  <div>
    <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  </div>
  <div appHideMe="hide">
    <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  </div>
  <div appHideMe>
    <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
  </div>
  <div>
    <mat-tab label="Fourth"> Content 4 </mat-tab>
  </div>

</mat-tab-group>

<div appHideMe>
  hidden
</div>
<div>
  visible
</div>
```

directive code

```ts
    @Directive({
      selector: '[appHideMe]'
    })
    export class HideMeDirective implements AfterViewInit {
    
      @Input() appHideMe: string;
    
      constructor(
        private el: ElementRef
      ) { }
    
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        
        if (this.appHideMe === 'hide') {
          this.el.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';
        }
        // should be displayed
        // this.el.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
```

As long as there is no `HideMeDirective` on div, `mat-dat` will be displayed. When `HideMeDirective` is added (see third `mat-tab`), that element is not visible. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to wrap `mat-tab` in a `div` element and adding `appHideMe` directive to wrapper tag.

Comment: Do you only need a solution for mat-tabs or do you want a generic solution for all html elements?

Comment: @Faisal I have role based we app and i have implemented directive which is checking if logged user has rights to see this tab. So only for tabs it would be great :)

Comment: @Tomp did you find an answer to this one, i am also having the same problem

Comment: @Kalanka nope. Maybe closest thing is [this](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#tabs-and-navigation)

Comment: @Tomp Chellappan's answer worked for me ..try with the `ref`

Comment: @TomP if u wrap mat-tab in a div with a directive, it just won't show up. Even that directive doesn't set display to none.

Answer (score 5):

Try Something like this

Define one variable

```ts
import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterViewInit,ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';   
@Directive({
    selector: '[appHideMe]',
    exportAs:'appHideMe',  
})
    
export class HideMeDirective implements AfterViewInit {   
    hide:Boolean;    
    constructor(
        private el: ElementRef,
        private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef
    ) { }
    
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.hide=false;
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }
}
```

Then use template ref

```ts
<mat-tab appHideMe #ref="appHideMe" label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
<mat-tab *ngIf="ref.hide" label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqc1co-vlw9aa

Answer (score 1):

`<mat-tab>` is just another directive generating more code that you don't see before executing. You have to hide a specific div that gets an id depending on the quantity of tabs.

[image]

That is why your hide-directive on the `<mat-tab>` directive does not work.

You have to write a directive that targets these elements using the classes as selector.

```
this.el.nativeElement.children
   .find(child => child.querySelector('.mat-tab-label') !== null)
.style.display == "none"; // there might be a better solution than that
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab appHideMe label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
<div appHideMe>
 <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
</div>

  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```