# How can I display a <mat-tab> element depending on a condition without using *ngIf?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dom, angular-material

I have the following code:

```
<mat-tab-group>
<mat-tab [hidden]="!file" label="Example">
Content
 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

I only want to display the first  if file exists. I cannot use *ngIf here because I am still accessing a reference variable in the template. It doesn't work with [hidden] as this is not an attribute of .

I have already tried the following.

1. `<mat-tab [ngStyle]="{'display' : file ? 'none' : 'block'}">`

works with mat-tab-group but not with mat-tab

2)

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab>
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
            <span [hidden]="!file">Example</span>
        </ng-template>
        Content
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

It ensures that "Example" is now only displayed if file exists, but the tab without the label remains visible.

3. If I specify a corresponding CSS class in mat-tab, it is simply ignored. This also happens if I add ViewEncapsulation: None in @Component.

Comment: Use this answer. Create a directive. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51872513/hide-angular-material-mat-tab-using-directive

Answer (score 0):

there is a workaround solution to this.
You can create an array of tabs and push/pop the tab based on whether file is true or not. the code will look somewhat like this.

```html
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index" [label]="tab">
    Contents for {{tab}} tab

    
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

in your ts whenever the condition !file is met just pop the tab from the array of tabs you have decalred.

-PS : I got this code snippet from https://v7.material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples. look at example "Tab group with dynamically changing tabs"